# django: uploading file mysterious issue

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I am running a multi-tenant app with nginx and gunicorn and where users upload files that get processed and then populate the db. When uploading small files (<2.5mo) everything works well, however when files gets bigger, I get a 502 bad gateway error.

Here is what seems to happen from the log:
nginx error.log

```
2020/05/17 17:03:25 [error] 6782#6782: *2 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

gunicorn.err.log

```
[2020-05-17 17:03:25 +0000] [6793] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6793
[2020-05-17 17:04:09 +0000] [6741] [INFO] Handling signal: term
[2020-05-17 17:04:10 +0000] [6741] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-05-17 17:04:12 +0000] [6799] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
```

Here is the view handling the import:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Getfiles(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    form_class = ETL
    logger.info('data acquired')
    success_url ='dash.html'



    def form_valid(self, form):
        url = self.request.build_absolute_uri()

        form.process_data(url)
        logger.debug('data has been processed')

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

With larger files, nothing gets logged for 'form.process.data(url) as well as nothing showing up in gunicorn.out.log. This leads me to think that the process data function does not get executed with larger files.

I am confuses because my settings in nginx and gunicorn seem to properly set (as far as very little experience speaks)

nginx.conf

```
server {
    server_name  mysite;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/fullchain.pem; # managed$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/mysite/privkey.pem; # manag$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/mysite/static/;
}

   location / {
        client_max_body_size 20M;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/mysite/app.sock;
}
```

and gunicorn conf works with worker-class Gevent to handle the uploads.

I cannot find anywhere what could cause the issue in django to prevent the processing from happening.

UPDATE:

After more research I found out that django does not handle small and big files the same way. Files <2.5 mo are store on memory while files greater than 2.5mo in size are upload in a temporary folder. 
In that case I am struggling to wrap my mind around how to handle that with nginx, how do i make sure that Nginx looks into two places for the files depending on their size?

I have tried adding the following line to settings.py from django documentation

```
MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = 52428800
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 52428800
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 52428800
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = None
```

this still does not work

Comment: Maybe the default 30 seconds [timeout](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout) of gunicorn is causing this?

Comment: I set gunicorn time out to 300 seconds and the error seems to be independant of the time. the files download file but then after 100% and a few seconds, 502 bad gateway occurs

Comment: Instead of keeping the thread open while uploading the file, did you tried using a background task or celery? Once you receive a request you can create a background task to upload the file and sent 202 Accepted response to client.

Comment: I have not tried celery yet, I am nervous about implementing new stuff without knowing what's the deal about the issue. What's a bit strange is that upgrading from a t2.micro ec2 instance to a t2.small instance have solved it but this still does not feel normal or is it?